# Как можно сделать перенос символов на следующую строку в qtableView?

Tags: qt

Вот код:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("EventBalancer");
db.setUserName("");
db.setPassword("");
if(!db.open()){
qDebug() << db.lastError().text() ;
}else
{
 qDebug() << "Success!\n";
}

model = new QSqlTableModel(this,db);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->setTable("TableEventBalancer");
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);

int id = QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont("/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf");
QFont font = QFont(QFontDatabase::applicationFontFamilies(id).first());
font.setPointSize(12);
ui->tableView->setFont(font);

ui->tableView->resizeColumnToContents(0);
ui->tableView->resizeColumnToContents(1);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Fixed);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(1, QHeaderView::Fixed);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::Stretch);
ui->tableView->verticalHeader()->setResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);

ui->tableView->setWordWrap(true);
ui->tableView->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideMiddle);

model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("number"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("ID"));
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("_date"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Дата"));
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("text"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Событие"));
```

Как можно сделать автоматический перенос символов на следующую строку в qtableView?

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6m6g.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#wordWrap-prop ?

Comment: @Nick Добавил 'ui->tableView->setWordWrap(true);' и 'ui->tableView->setTextElideMode(Qt::ElideMiddle);' но переноса нет. В конце ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572929/qtableview-with-multiline-cell/16575453#16575453 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46431491/qtableview-to-show-the-content-of-table-item-when-mouse-hover/46434909#46434909

Comment: @S. Nick еще вопросик, Перенос строки заработал. Но когда вводишь текст в поле 'событие' не происходит перенос. Текст вытягивается в длину, а когда заканчиваешь ввод, происходит перенос.